# Where to find the default highlighting schema of code on github?

Tags: github, token, syntax-highlighting

Where can I find the file for the default code highlighting theme of Github? All languages, tokens and their respective rgb colours? The code font seems to be Consolas, but I need more information on the colours specifically.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I believe you are looking for https://github.com/github/linguist/blob/master/vendor/README.md

Linguist is the repository that hosts the code responsible for language breakdown stats, and it uses the repos detailed in the link for syntax highlighting on GitHub.

For the colors, you will need to search the list for the specific language you are interested in.